# How can I implement `From<some trait's associated type>?`

Tags: rust

I'm writing a new crate, and I want it to be useable with any implementation of a trait (defined in another crate). The trait looks something like this:

```rust
pub trait Trait {
   type Error;
   ...
}
```

I have my own `Error` type, but sometimes I just want to forward the underlying error unmodified. My instinct is to define a type like this:

```rust
pub enum Error<T: Trait> {
    TraitError(T::Error),
    ...
}
```

This is similar to the pattern encouraged by [thiserror](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror), and appears to be idiomatic. It works fine, but I also want to use `?` in my implementation, so I need to implement `From`:

```rust
impl<T: Trait> From<T::Error> for Error<T> {
    fn from(e: T::Error) -> Self { Self::TraitError(e) }
}
```

That fails, because it conflicts with `impl<T> core::convert::From<T> for T`. I think I understand why — some other implementor of `Trait` could set `type Error = my_crate::Error` such that both `impl`s would apply — but how else can I achieve similar semantics?

I've looked at a few other crates, and they seem to handle this by making their `Error` (or equivalent) generic over the error type itself, rather than the trait implementation. That works, of course, but:

- until we have [inherent associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/8995), it's much more verbose. My `T` actually implements multiple traits, each with their own `Error` types, so I'd now have to return types like `Result<..., Error<<T as TraitA>::Error, <T as TraitB>::Error>>` etc;
- it's arguably less expressive (because the relationship to `Trait` is lost).

Is making my `Error` generic over the individual types the best (most idiomatic) option today?

Comment: Instead of implementing `From`, you could use `.map_err(Error::TraitError)?` instead of simply `?`, this way the error type is already `Error` instead of `T::Error` and `?` will use the blanket `impl<T> From<T> for T` with `T = Error`.

Comment: Yes, that works, and thinking about it is the _only_ way it can work. The `From` trait just operates on a type, it doesn't know where it came from. What happens if `TraitA::Error` and `TraitB::Error` have the same type?

I still have to make `Error` generic, but it can be generic over just one type, not every individual trait.

Comment: Couldn't you bind `T` with `T: TraitA + TraitB` and have two variants in `Error`, one `TraitA(<T as TraitA>::Error)` and another as `TraitB(<T as TraitB>::Error)` and `.map_err(...)?` depending on which trait is used? Even if they had the same type, they'd be in distinct variants, and you don't need to implement `From` for `Error` if using `.map_err(...)?`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have, since trying your `map_err()` suggestion. The only problem I've found so far is that it's still verbose (compared to `?`), but the public API is very concise.

Now I'm wondering why I haven't seen this used elsewhere.

Comment: The verbosity is required to specify which variant you want to return, I believe this is standard practise when implementing `From` isn't viable, as it's what `map_err` was designed for. If this has solved your problem, I'll post an answer summarising the solution.

Comment: Please do, and thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing `From` for your `Error` enum, consider instead using [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) in combination with `?` to specify which variant to return.
This works even for enums generic over a type using associated types, as such:

```rust
trait TraitA {
  type Error;
  fn do_stuff(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

trait TraitB {
  type Error;
  fn do_other_stuff(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

enum Error<T: TraitA + TraitB> {
  DoStuff(<T as TraitA>::Error),
  DoOtherStuff(<T as TraitB>::Error),
}

fn my_function<T: TraitA + TraitB>(t: T) -> Result<(), Error<T>> {
  t.do_stuff().map_err(Error::DoStuff)?;
  t.do_other_stuff().map_err(Error::DoOtherStuff)?;
  Ok(())
}
```

[On the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bbf06c20ac99f6fe2b16be1418d2d8d)

Here the important bits are that `Error` has no `From` implementations (aside from blanket ones), and that the variant is specified using `map_err`. This works as `Error::DoStuff` can be interpreted as a `fn(<T as TraitA>::Error) -> Error` when passed to `map_err`. Same happens with `Error::DoOtherStuff`.

This approach is scaleable with however many variants `Error` has and whether or not they are the same type. It might also be clearer to someone reading the function, as they can figure out that a certain error comes from a certain place without needing to check `From` implementations and where the type being converted from appears in the function.